# Find days of week based on weekdays mask value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a weekdays mask number which represents the sum of some days of the week:

```
SUNDAY = ((2**0))
MONDAY = ((2**1))
TUESDAY = ((2**2))
weekdays_mask = SUNDAY + MONDAY + TUESDAY
```

So if I have the sum of these days stored in DB how can I do the reverse process and find what days of week I will have to display based on the `weekdays_mask` value. Does anyone know a method for doing this? Thank you!

Comment: BTW, you can also use `1 << 0`, `1 << 1`, `1 << 2` or `0b001`, `0b010`, `0b100` to define the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is a bit uncommon. You'd usually use *bitwise OR* to combine the values:

```
SUNDAY | MONDAY | TUESDAY #=> 7
SUNDAY | MONDAY           #=> 3
```

and *bitwise AND* to check for a specific value:

```
days = SUNDAY | MONDAY

days & SUNDAY  #=> 1
days & MONDAY  #=> 2
days & TUESDAY #=> 0   <- zero indicates bit not set
```

Answer (score 2):

You could initialise them by the 0b0000-like pattern and instead of +/- then use binary arithmetics instead;

```
SUNDAY    = 0b000000
MONDAY    = 0b000001
TUESDAY   = 0b000010
WEDNESDAY = 0b000100
THURSDAY  = 0b001000
FRIDAY    = 0b010000
SATURDAY  = 0b100000

weekend = SATURDAY | SUNDAY
workday = MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY

is_friday_weekend = weekend & FRIDAY
# => 0

is_friday_workday = workday & FRIDAY
# => 16 (Which is not 0; so yes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way, bit here my 2 cents, based on three days, but works also adding more days:

```
SUNDAY = ((2**0))
MONDAY = ((2**1))
TUESDAY = ((2**2))
weekdays_mask_7 = SUNDAY | MONDAY | TUESDAY
weekdays_mask_6 = MONDAY | TUESDAY
weekdays_mask_5 = SUNDAY | TUESDAY
weekdays_mask_4 = TUESDAY
weekdays_mask_3 = SUNDAY | MONDAY
weekdays_mask_2 = MONDAY
weekdays_mask_1 = SUNDAY

days = %w[SUNDAY MONDAY TUESDAY]

weekdays_mask = weekdays_mask_7 # just to play

day_array = (weekdays_mask.to_s(2).split("").map(&:to_i).reverse).zip(days)
day_array.select{|e| p e[1] if e[0] == 1}
```